# Adding varchar value and datetime in MS SQL

Tags: sql, datetime, time, hour

I need some help with a query.

I have the following columns:

```
Fulltime (datetime)
Hour (varchar)
```

I need to convert the Hour into time format, and add it into the `Fulltime`

For example:

```
Fulltime = 2009-10-10 00:00:00:000
Hour = 10:30
Result = 2009-10-10 10:30:00:000
```

I found many ways to convert varchar to a datetime, but it always add a date into the result.

Comment: which DBMS are you using? is it MS SQL Server or MySQL or some other?

Comment: You can simply add the two together - `SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '2009-10-10 00:00:00:000', 120) + CAST('10:30' AS TIME)`

Comment: I tries it and got the following error:the data types datetime and time are incompatible in the add operator

Comment: Hmm it would appear they are compatible in SQL Server 2008, but not in SQL Server 2012. You would need to cast your time to `DATETIME` instead of `TIME` - `SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '2009-10-10 00:00:00:000', 120) + CAST('10:30' AS DATETIME)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cast `Hour` as datetime and add it in `Fulltime` like :

```
Select Fulltime + CAST(Hour as DATETIME)
```

and if you want the remove existing time part and add the hour then :

```
SELECT Cast(Cast(Fulltime AS DATE) AS DATETIME)
       + Cast(Hour AS DATETIME)
```

Comment: May I know the reason of down vote. Is something wrong in this then I would really like to know.. :) thanks

Comment: Well, it wasn't me to vote your answer down, but it just checked it and it's works properly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT '2009-10-10 00:00:00:000' + CONVERT(DATETIME, CAST ('10:30' AS time))
```

And replace the string representations with your variables/columns